# Referencing other workbooks to populate cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two excel work books "sites.xlsx" and "site template blank.xlsx" that I working with, and I want to populate cells on the "site template" using criteria from the "sites" workbook.  Below is what I've tried.

```
=IF([sites.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2="Alt";[Site Template blank.xlsx]Sheet1!F2="Red cross";IF([sites.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2="Primary";[Site Template blank.xlsx]Sheet1!B2="Snapshot";))
```

So basically if it says "Alt" it should display "Red cross" and else if it say "Primary" it should display "Snapshot". Can someone show me how to fix what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You mean like this? `=IF([sites.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2="Alt";"Red cross";IF([sites.xlsx]Sheet1!$D$2="Primary";"Snapshot";""))`

Comment: Your answer looks like what I'm trying to accomplish but, I'm still getting an error.  It highlights the word "Alt" and one of the ) at the end.

Comment: That is because I doubt your separators are `;`. Replace then with `,` and try again

Comment: =IF([sites.xlsx]Sheet1!D2="Alt","Red cross",IF([sites.xlsx]Sheet1!D2="Primary","Snapshot",""))     That did it thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out :)